# Add padding around Facebook iframe app

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-iframe

I've got a Facebook iframe app, using fluid width.

I can't work out how to create space between this app and the **outside** top content, left margin and right content.

Currently, there is no space between my Facebook app and surrounding outside content.

Have tried various CSS `padding` and `margin` but these add spacing to the content **inside** the iframe app.

Here's relevant markup as requested (thanks).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- various FB metadata -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=0.5, user-scalable=yes" />

     <title>Slideshow</title>
  </head>

  <body
    <div id="slideshow">
    <!-- various html/jquery for slideshow -->
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin-top: 20px; padding-top: 20px; /* only works with content INSIDE the app */

  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  background-size: cover;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #e5e5e5 0%,#5e8cba 100%); /* W3C */

  /* browser-specific elided */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A) close your body tag with a >

```
<body>
```

B) padding only works on the inside. Always. And I don't believe margin works in that content. Try adding a div outside, and give padding to that.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
<!-- various FB metadata -->
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=0.5,                    user-scalable=yes" />

 <title>Slideshow</title>
 </head>

<body>
<div style="padding:5px">
<div id="slideshow">
<!-- various html/jquery for slideshow -->
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I missed the `>` from `<body>` in the transcription. I tried the padding as per your example but unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: What is you added a margin to the body of the facebook app?